# How to find and update a mongoose model?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, loopbackjs

I have a model userDatas and it contain a list of user data.

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bb6730721f28a295436b36f"),
    "userId" : "5bb6730721f28a295436b36e",
    "reputationNumber" : 0,
    "questions" : [],
    "answers" : []
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bb6738c21f28a295436b371"),
    "userId" : "5bb6738c21f28a295436b370",
    "reputationNumber" : 0,
    "questions" : [],
    "answers" : []
}]
```

I want to filter by userId and add "5bb7d72af050ca0910282ff4" string to  questions array. How to accomplish that?

```
//Userdatas.find
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using mongoose you can use the [findOneAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) and [addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) to achieve this:

```
Userdatas.findOneAndUpdate(
   {userId: "5bb7d72af050ca0910282ff4"}, 
   {$addToSet: {questions: '5bb7d72af050ca0910282ff4'}}, 
   function (err, result) {
     ...
   }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The query would look something like

```
Userdatas.findOne({where: {userId: "5bb7d72af050ca0910282ff4"}}, function (err, data) {
        if (!err && data) {
            var questionsArr = [];
            if (data.questions) {
                questionsArr = data.questions;
            }
            questionsArr.push('5bb7d72af050ca0910282ff4');
            data.updateAttributes({questions: questionsArr}, function(err, updateData) {
                cb (err, updateData);
            });
        } else {
            cb (err, {});
        }
    });
```

Unfortunately you would need 2 queries to do this. First, to get the document where the userId matches your required userId and to push the string to the questions array and update the document.

EDIT: 
The first findOne query fetches the document where userId matches our user. The updateAttributes query is executed on the document that was fetched, so it updates the correct document.

Comment: Thanks @Sashi. How does Userdatas.updateAttributes({questions: questionsArr}, function(err, updateData) {
                cb (err, updateData);
            }); know which userdata update?

Comment: Sorry @HenokTesfaye, I made a mistake with the code. I have corrected the code and added an explanation as well. Sorry and thanks